# Communicating among functions

Tags: python, python-3.2

Here I have this code which calculates the distance a bouncing ball would travel. The problem lies in the functions display summary and the 3 functions that follow it. On line three while I am defining calculateTotalDistIn() I realize that the function does not know what the variable bounceNum is or any other variables that follow it. Is there any way I can somehow send the variables values without using global variables? Thank you.

```
def askName(name):
    yourName = name.upper()
    return yourName

def displaySummary():
    calculateTotalDistin()
    print("Bouncy index % given was: ", str(index))
    print("Start height given was: ", str(height))

def programmerID():
    print("\n")
    print("Bertrand Zhu")
    print("Period 7")
    print("Roster#: 20")
    print("\n")

def displaySummary():
    index = float(input("What is your bouncy Index % ? "))
    newIndex = index/100
    height = int(input("What is your starting height in inches? "))v\
    bounceNum = int(input("How many bounces would you like? "))
    distance = calculateTotalDistIn()
    distanceFT = calculateTotalDistFT()
    distanceCT = calculateTotalDistCT()
    print("Bouncy Index % given was " + str(index))
    print("Start Height given was " + str(height))
    print("Bounce Count Given was " + str(bounceNum))
    print("\n")
    print("Distance Inches: " + distance)
    print("Distance Feet: " + distanceFT)
    print("Distance Centimeters " + distanceCT)

def calculateTotalDistIn():
    distance = 0
    count = 0
    while count <= bounceNum:
        modHeight = height * newIndex
        distance += modHeight
        count = 1
        height = modHeight
    return distance

def calculateTotalDistFT():
    distance = 0
    count = 0
    while count <= bounceNum:
        modHeight = height * newIndex
        distance += modHeight
        count = 1
        height = modHeight
    distFT = float(distance/12)
    return distFT

def calculateTotalDistCT():
    distance = 0
    count = 0
    while count <= bounceNum:
        modHeight = height * newIndex
        distance += modHeight
        count = 1
        height = modHeight
    distCT = float(distance*(2.54))
    return distCT

def goodbye(varX):
    print("Goodbye, " + varX)

def main():
    while True:
        name = input("What is your name? ")
        yourName = askName(name)
        if yourName == "QUIT":
            break
        else:
            programmerID()
            displaySummary()
    goodbye()

#Run the Program
main()
```

Comment: you can simply pass it as an argument to the function

Comment: You can do what Hamms said, but you can also do something more structured and use [classes](http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex40.html) instead of just functions to structure your program as a whole. Moving beyond just functions is an important part of developing as a programmer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options: one is to pass the values as parameters, the other is to define a class for each category of object, and have them manipulate their own data. I'll give you an example of option 1:

### Option1: Pass parameters

```
def displaySummary():
    index = float(input("What is your bouncy Index % ? "))
    newIndex = index/100
    height = int(input("What is your starting height in inches? "))v\
    bounceNum = int(input("How many bounces would you like? "))
    distance = calculateTotalDistCT(height, newIndex, bounceNum)
    ...


def calculateTotalDistCT(height, newIndex, bounceNum):
    distance = 0
    count = 0
    while count <= bounceNum:
        modHeight = height * newIndex
        distance += modHeight
        count = 1
        height = modHeight
    distCT = distance * 2.54
    return distCT
```

You can look up the many OOP tutorials available freely.

Comment: What are OOP tutorials?

Comment: Thank you for helping me BTW

Comment: Very welcome. OOP is Object Oriented Programming (classes)

Comment: @bertrand Classes are one of the more advanced concepts, but are very powerful one you learn them.

Answer (score 2):

You should pass tha variables you want to use inside your methods as params.

For example:

```
def displaySummary():
    bounceNum = int(input("How many bounces would you like? "))
    newIndex = index/100
    height = int(input("What is your starting height in inches? "))
    calculateTotalDistin(bounceNum, height, newIndex)
    print("Bouncy index % given was: ", str(index))
    print("Start height given was: ", str(height))

def calculateTotalDistIn(bounceNum, height, newIndex):
    distance = 0
    count = 0
    while count <= bounceNum:
        modHeight = height * newIndex
        distance += modHeight
        count = 1
        height = modHeight
    return distance
```

But, instead of doing so I would recommend to you that use classes. Then, you could have better structure methods and code.

Comment: Oh. That did not occur to me. Stupid me.

Comment: Haha, You're welcome. And don't worry, that things sometimes happen.